# How to rotate camera towards point in 3d?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got a camera somewhere in a 3d space. I need to **calculate angle between camera and a given point**.

I can't use `lookAt()` method (nor any built-in `Controller`), because I'm also rotating camera on mousemove and want to animate the rotation.

In a word: how to change `camera.rotation` to make it look at specified point?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach for rotating a 3D object towards a target is the usage of [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards). It's usage is demonstrated in the official example [webgl_math_orientation_transform](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_math_orientation_transform).

The important bit of this approach is:

```js
camera.quaternion.rotateTowards( targetQuaternion, step );
```

`targetQuaternion` represents the target orientation whereas `step` represents the angular step in radians. This value should honor the time delta for a correct animation.

Comment: I'm wondering how to put my point (`THREE.Vector3`) into that method. Can I convert `Vector3` into `Quaternion` somehow?

Comment: No. You need a target orientation that defines the final rotation state of your camera.

Comment: But that's the main problem for me. I don't know how to calculate the rotation :)

Comment: You normally do this with `lookAt()` like in the example code. I'm afraid it's not clear from your first post why you can't use this approach in your code.

Comment: I cannot use `lookAt()` **directly** on my camera because it affects its rotation immediately. I've got one method to set camera position and rotation - it gathered few things (I'm combining camera path animation with mousemove look-around) and recalculating them in one place.
Now I'm trying to call `lookAt()` on new temporary `Camera` object which is a copy of my main camera. And then to read it's new `rotation`.

Comment: Notice than you can also use `lookAt()` on an instance of a `Matrix4` which can then be used to setup the target quaternion. This is how it's done in the example. In this way, you don't need a temporary camera.